# Why do we use PendingIntent in notifications?

Tags: java, android, notifications, android-pendingintent

I am somewhat new to android app development. I was wondering why we use `pendingIntent` while creating notifications.

I have read this in the docs(https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/navigation):

> this page describes how you set up a PendingIntent for your
> notification's action so it creates a fresh task and back stack

However, I can't wrap my head around how a PendingIntent creates a fresh task and back stack.

All help is appreciated. Thank you!!

Comment: android studio is the IDE you're using to create android apps, but it has nothing to do with your question here. if you're asking about the IDE, add the tag, otherwise it's fine to just use `android`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was wondering why we use pendingIntent while creating notifications.

Read [the PendingIntent documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent). Specifically this bit:

> A PendingIntent itself is simply a reference to a token maintained by the system describing the original data used to retrieve it. This means that, even if its owning application's process is killed, the PendingIntent itself will remain usable from other processes that have been given it.

In other words - you use a PendingIntent for a notification because a notification can sit in the user's notification area for an indefinite amount of time, during which your app may have been killed.

> However, I can't wrap my head around how a PendingIntent creates a fresh task and back stack.

It doesn't. You do, [as explained in the very article you linked](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/navigation#build_a_pendingintent_with_a_back_stack).

Answer (score -1):

I would like to explain in a very simple way. Pending mean there is something pending and as you can see it is Pending Intent which means there is a intent which is pending and waiting for some action to perform. Like if you tap on the notification is takes you to some place of screen that navigation is pending you click the notification. Hope you got it! Adios.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response, although that wasn't really my question. How does it create a fresh task and back stack?

Comment: The destination of Pending intent is always an activity as you might know activity is it self a process. It is just triggering the process to execute. Just like launcher activity you explicitly tells your app that you have a entry point which should create whenever user taps on launcher icon. On launcher icon click it executes a thread which is main thread and on that thread activity.